# is there some difference of component in flex3 and flex4

Tags: apache-flex, difference

there some weird problems in my project,I download the **objecthandles** project which let  make a component draggable,resizeable,stretchable and rotatable.

it works well in flex3,then in flex4,I add decorator(a Sprite object) to the spark component,any component,such as group,button and so on ,the decorator not show,but the functon `addElement()`,it was executed.

so I want to konw the difference between flex3  and flex4,or what I do to shield the spark component mouseClick event,I have tried the mouseenable or focusEnable，they did not work.

Answer (score 2):

flex4 has spark components, while flex3 has mx components. In flex4 however, you can still use the old mx components, if you allow it in the project setup. spark components are usually lighter, faster, more reliable, but contain less features than in mx components. 
A Sprite is not a flex object, it is pure AS3. Since it is not a flex component, it is not added by addElement(), rather with addChild().

Comment: In Flex 4; you can use a SpriteVisualElement http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/core/SpriteVisualElement.html as a "Flex" version of the Sprite.  The addChild() will throw a runtime error if used on a Spark Container.

Comment: yes,I just use spritevisualelement,but it still not show,the decorator object(sprite),I add it like this: container.addElement(decorator as IVisualElement)

Comment: the problem has been solved.I just set the spark component skin's property, enabled=false,but I still can not find the reason,or just the skin principle